# [Qt ROS plug-in] Cannot import self-defined messages

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I'm trying to develop a GUI for a project to command easily a robot. I've made my own self-defined messages and tested them and everything works fine. The thing is that when I try to use this message on my `user_interface`package (I've created it by using `catkin_create_qt_create user_interface` command on my `ws_dir/src` file), the compiler cannot find `project_msgs/my_msg.h`. I left here the configuration of my `CMakeList.txt` file and my `package.xml` file, because I do not know what I am doing wrong.

**CMakeList.txt:**

```
##############################################################################
# CMake
##############################################################################
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.0)
project(user_interface)

## Compile as C++11, supported in ROS Kinetic and newer
add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

##############################################################################
# Catkin
##############################################################################

# qt_build provides the qt cmake glue, roscpp the comms for a default talker
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS qt_build roscpp) #project_msgs

#find_package(Qt REQUIRED Core Widgets)
#set(QT_LIBRARIES Qt5::Widgets)
include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
# Use this to define what the package will export (e.g. libs, headers).
catkin_package(INCLUDE_DIRS include
               LIBRARIES user_interface
               CATKIN_DEPENDS qt_build
                              roscpp
                              project_msgs
               DEPENDS system_lib)

##############################################################################
# Qt Environment
##############################################################################
# this comes from qt_build's qt-ros.cmake which is automatically 
# included via the dependency call in package.xml
rosbuild_prepare_qt4(QtCore QtGui) # Add the appropriate components to the component list here

##############################################################################
# Sections
##############################################################################
file(GLOB QT_FORMS RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ui/*.ui)
file(GLOB QT_RESOURCES RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} resources/*.qrc)
file(GLOB_RECURSE QT_MOC RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} FOLLOW_SYMLINKS include/user_interface/*.hpp)

QT4_ADD_RESOURCES(QT_RESOURCES_CPP ${QT_RESOURCES})
QT4_WRAP_UI(QT_FORMS_HPP ${QT_FORMS})
QT4_WRAP_CPP(QT_MOC_HPP ${QT_MOC})

##############################################################################
# Sources
##############################################################################
file(GLOB_RECURSE QT_SOURCES RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} FOLLOW_SYMLINKS src/*.cpp)

##############################################################################
# Binaries
##############################################################################
add_executable(user_interface ${QT_SOURCES} ${QT_RESOURCES_CPP} ${QT_FORMS_HPP} ${QT_MOC_HPP})
add_dependencies(user_interface ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
target_link_libraries(user_interface ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
install(TARGETS user_interface RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION})
```

**package.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>user_interface</name>
  <version>0.1.0</version>
  <description>
         user_interface
      </description>
  <maintainer email="*********@******">*******</maintainer>
  <author>********</author>
  <license>BSD</license>
  <!-- <url type="bugtracker">https://github.com/stonier/qt_ros/issues</url> -->
  <!-- <url type="repository">https://github.com/stonier/qt_ros</url> -->

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>qt_build</build_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>libqt4-dev</build_depend>
  <build_depend>project_msgs</build_depend>
  <run_depend>qt_build</run_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>libqt4-dev</run_depend>
  <run_depend>project_msgs</run_depend>
 
</package>
```

ROS Version: Kinetic (Ubuntu 16.04)

**EDIT 1**
`project_msgs\CMakeLists.txt` :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(project_msgs)
## Compile as C++11, supported in ROS Kinetic and newer
add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  message_generation
  #geometry_msgs
)

################################################
## Declare ROS messages, services and actions ##
################################################
## Generate services in the 'srv' folder
add_service_files(
  FILES
  my_msg.srv
)

## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES
  std_msgs
)


###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES project_msgs
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp
                 rospy
                 std_msgs
                 message_runtime
                 #geometry_msgs
  DEPENDS system_lib
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
include_directories(
# include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342432/%5Bqt-ros-plug-in%5D-cannot-import-self-defined-messages/) by [drodgu](https://answers.ros.org/users/43205/drodgu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 59 on 2020-01-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You don't specify in your `CMakeLists.txt` that your package `user_interface` needs the package `project_msgs`. You have to specify it using [find_package](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt#Finding_Dependent_CMake_Packages) :

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS qt_build roscpp project_msgs)
```

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2020-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [drodgu](https://answers.ros.org/users/43205/drodgu/) on 2020-01-24**:
Thank you for answering so quickly! And I've get this error message on compilation `Project 'user_interface' tried to find library 'project_msgs'.  The library is neither a target nor built/installed properly.  Did you compile project 'project_msgs'? Did you find_package() it before the subdirectory containing its code is included?` And the package is already compiled because I've use it on another package to test it. I've have all the packages under the same `ws_application/src` file.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2020-01-24**:
You said in your question that your message was propperly defined but that might not be the case, can you show the `CMakeLists.txt` of the package `project_msgs` please ?

**Comment by [drodgu](https://answers.ros.org/users/43205/drodgu/) on 2020-01-25**:
Yes, I will edit the question in order to include the `CMakeLists.txt`of `project_msg`packages.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2020-01-28**:
From [#q210301](https://answers.ros.org/question/210301/cmake-error-for-depending-two-custom-packages/) : you should remove the line `LIBRARIES project_msgs` since you don't create the library `project_msgs`.

**Comment by [drodgu](https://answers.ros.org/users/43205/drodgu/) on 2020-01-28**:
Thank you so much, it works!